# Highcharts label at absolute top left?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I position my custom label at the VERY TOP LEFT of the chart?

I tried doing this:

```
labels: {
  items: [{
      html: 'Testing Custom Label',
      style: {
        left: '0px',
        top: '0px',
        color: 'red'
      }
    }],
    style: {
      position: 'absolute'
    }
}
```

but it doesn't take the yaxis / title into consideration. Is there a way to do this which will work for ANY chart instead of me hardcoding some negative values for top/left (which will only work for this particular chart) ?

http://jsfiddle.net/itsVicc/xu9nL8cn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **renderer** to generate the label instead of doing this via chart constructor options. The label will be positioned using the whole chart (not plot area) as baseline.

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
       this.renderer.label('test label', 0, 0).add();
    }
  }
},
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/ns3rh6rx/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label